# Relation between PCA eigen values and data visualization

Tags: pca, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

We have matrix data $X$ which is $n\times d$. We use the covariance matrix/ design matrix/ gram matrix $X^T X$ to perform least-squares/ PCA. I compute the eigen basis representation of said matrix

$$X^TX = \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i u_i u_i^T.$$

I notice that $\lambda_d \geq \sqrt{n}$. Can I infer that there must have been at least $\sqrt{n}$ data $\{x_t\}_{t=1}^n$ (which forms the rows of the big matrix $X$) from the direction prependicular to $u_1$

PS : assume data $\{x_t\}$ to come from the d-dimesion sphere so that $\|x\|_2 = 1$

PS: I would be very tempted to say the number of data $x_t$ close to some region of $u_d$ is more than $\sqrt{n}$, but I guess thats asking for too much

Comment: This question said: $$X^TX = \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$$. $${}$$ If you look at the MathJax edit I did, it will become clear why the period you put at the end of your sentence appeared on the next line rather than where a period normally would be. I changed it to the following: $$X^TX = \sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i u_i u_i^T.$$

Comment: Pick any number $N \gt 1.$  Consider the $1\times 1$ matrix $X=(N).$  In this case $\lambda_d=N^2\gt 1 = \sqrt{n}.$